# MYSQL query table using column position, NOT column name

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to write a query like the one below?

```
UPDATE sale SET sale_order='123456789' WHERE **COLUMN_1** = 2
```

where I don't explicitly pass the column name? Only its position?

I could get the column names but I am trying to avoid querying the database only to get them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, no, there is no syntax in SQL to reference the column by its position. This goes back to relational theory, in the sense that a table is a *set* of columns, and members of a set are unordered.

You will either have to know the column name, or else query it from the database:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=SCHEMA() AND TABLE_NAME='sale' 
  AND ORDINAL_POSITION=1;
```

It looks like you are trying to design a query that updates a row by primary key, by assuming the first column is the primary key. The primary key isn't necessarily the first column. It isn't necessarily an integer. It isn't necessarily a single column.

So you are already making assumptions about the table definition. You might as well assume the primary key column is named `id` or some other convention.

Comment: You are correct that I want to update a row by primary key. All tables in my database have a numeric primary key as the first column. I was trying to save having to pass a parameter with the column name. Thanks.